# Stacking Divs in Reverse order Responsively

Tags: css

I have two div's that are side by side in a wider screen (say 1000 px)

Box 1 is the left of Box 2

When I change the screen size to say 330px, I want Box 2 ABOVE Box 1.

I have no issues getting BOX 1 ABOVE Box 2, but not the reverse.

I'm hoping this can be done with css - I can make it happen with javascript.

Comment: For this to be a good question, you would show your code and what you have tried.

Comment: Your statements are contradictory 

I want Box 2 ABOVE Box1
no issues getting BOX 1 ABOVE Box 2...but not the reverse
Well not the reverse the reverse would be Box2 stacked on Box1 which you initially asked for.
Please specify the problem correctly.

Comment: @Novice: It makes sense as it is, there's no contradiction: OP wants box 2 above box 1, but with everything they've tried box 1 appears above box 2 (which they don't want), but they can't get it to do the reverse (2 above 1, which they do want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a media query to modify CSS rules under certain screen width:

```css
div {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #7A9;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 331px) {
  #box1 {
    float: left;
  }
  #box2 {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box2">BOX 2</div>
<div id="box1">BOX 1</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are saying about responsiveness, `@media` queries come into play. I don't fishing care about Old IE versions, so I am using FlexBox for your solution. We can have reverse and orders in flexbox.

**Snippet**

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

div {border: 1px solid #ccc; max-width: 100px;}
div div {width: 50px; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;}

@media (max-width: 330px) {
  .flex-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .flex-item {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
</div>
```

Another option for older browsers with just using float in a cunning way.

**Snippet with Floats**

```css
div {border: 1px solid #ccc; max-width: 104px;}
div div {width: 50px; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;}

div {overflow: hidden;}
div div {float: left;}
div div:first-child {float: right;}

@media (max-width: 330px) {
  div div {float: none;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```